# Processing while a timer is running

Tags: java, memory-management, operating-system

How can I run a process while a timer is running in the program. Here's a sample layout of what I mean. Or is it possible to have this kind of layout?

```
 __________________________________
|                             8:00 |
|@8:00 Job 1 arrives and start...  |
|@8:30 Job 2 arrives and wait...   |
|...                               |
|...                               |
```

Comment: Do you want Job 2 to wait until Job 1 stops, or wait until a certain time?  Or is this irrelevant to your question and you just want to be able to tell when a new job arrived?

Comment: I want to make Job 2 wait and is also logged below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this.  Here is one.

```
 Thread t42  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          myBackgroundMethod();
      }
 });
 t42.setDeamon(true);
 t42.start();
```

Comment: Another way is to use a TimerTask:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Another way is to use  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html

Answer (score 1):

use a Thread, it makes a process run simultaneously. [heres](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) a tutorial on how to use threads.